# F SDK 4.0.0: GraphRequest from facebook returns null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following code and what I want to obtain is **user's friends names, user's friends profile pictures and user's friends facebook id**:

```
public void testFunction(final com.facebook.AccessToken access_token){
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            access_token,
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(
                        JSONObject object,
                        GraphResponse response) {
                    if(object != null) {
                        Log.wtf("FIRST", "JSONOBJECT: IS NULL");
                    }else {
                        Log.wtf("FIRST", "JSONOBJECT: " + object.toString());
                    }

                    if(response != null) {
                        Log.wtf("FIRST", "RESPONSE: IS NULL");
                    }else {
                        Log.wtf("FIRST","response: "+response.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}

public void getFriendsInformation(final com.facebook.AccessToken access_token) {

    GraphRequestBatch batch = new GraphRequestBatch(
            GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    access_token,
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject jsonObject,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            if(jsonObject != null) {
                                Log.wtf("FIRST", "JSONOBJECT: IS NULL");
                            }else {
                                Log.wtf("FIRST", "JSONOBJECT: " + jsonObject.toString());
                            }

                            if(response != null) {
                                Log.wtf("FIRST", "RESPONSE: IS NULL");
                            }else {
                                Log.wtf("FIRST","response: "+response.toString());
                            }
                            // Application code for user
                        }
                    }),
            GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(
                    access_token,
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONArray jsonArray,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                        if(jsonArray != null) {
                            Log.wtf("SECOND", "jsonArray: IS NULL");
                        }else {
                            Log.wtf("SECOND", "jsonArray: " + jsonArray.toString());
                        }

                            if(response != null) {
                                Log.wtf("SECOND", "RESPONSE: IS NULL");
                            }else {
                                Log.wtf("SECOND","response: "+response.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    })
    );
    batch.addCallback(new GraphRequestBatch.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onBatchCompleted(GraphRequestBatch graphRequests) {
            // Application code for when the batch finishes
        }
    });
    batch.executeAsync();
}
```

When I run the code with the accessToken **IS NULL** is printed in the designated logs. Shouldn't this work?

Comment: In your checks you are saying `if (object != null)`, log that the object is null. The conditional you are doing will check if the object has data, is that your issue. Your code should be:
`if (object != null) { 
  Log.wtf("FIRST", "JSONOBJECT: " + object.toString)
} else {
  Log.wtf("FIRST", "JSONOBJECT: IS NULL");
}`

Comment: @The1Fitz lol yeah, my bad, tyvm